# How to store the settings of the app using the IASKSettingsStore

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, inappsettingskit

i am using the InAppSettingsKit, but i have no idea how to save the settings of the app using the IASKSettingsStore Class. when i closes my application and reopen it, the settings are set to the default options.

Comment: ya i would use NSUserDefaults or u could try a singleton+coredata

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't need `IASKSettingsStore`. Then, IASK uses the standard `NSUserDefaults` mechanism from the Settings app.

`IASKSettingsStore` is needed only if you wish to use alternative storing mechanisms such as storing the settings in files, Core Data, iCloud etc.